# How to proceed if employer ends the job for inappropriate reason?

Tags: employer-relations

When I graduated from my school, a company hired me as an intern. They had potential to hire as a full-time, but they wanted to see how I perform before hiring for full-time. I had several interviews for intern position, and then they offered me a 3 months internship. After 3 weeks suddenly human resource person gave me a check of 5 weeks pay and told that my skills are different and I should another position. 
3 weeks is a pretty short time and no one can judge the engineers' performance in that time. I had to perform for 3 months and then they had to make a decision and that was the standard way.
I am sure it's unfair with me, and I should contact department of labor to know if an employer can treat interns like that. Internship is a program for skill enhancement, and if employer is not going to hire the intern as a full-time, that doesn't mean they would end the internship.
I wanted that employer to pay my rest of the contract period pay because it was a 3 months internship, but they told that I didn't perform well. Engineers can't be judged in 3 weeks and that's why I was given 3 months.
Is there any govt agency that can help me with this matter? I understand that it's against corporate ethics.
That employer is based in bay area.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you take a look at the FAQ for what makes a good question. What you've asked is more of a rant rather than a concise question.

Comment: No-one can tell you if there's a government agency or not without knowing what country's government might have authority in your situation. Please add a location tag.

Comment: What does your contract say about termination?

Comment: I am sorry, but to put it bluntly, if you do not think an Engineering manager can tell within 3 weeks if you are qualified to perform at the level they need, then you already have demonstrated you are not qualified.  Things like evaluation internships and 30 or 60 day probationary periods would be meaningless if such evaluations could not be made that quickly.  From my experience, paying you 5 weeks for 3 weeks of under-performance is very generous.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you were hired as an at-will employee. That means, you can be dismissed with reason (in this case, underperformance would be a valid reason) from your employer. Now unless your employers openly discriminated you as a member of a protected class, there is no other means left for you. Consider filing for unemployment if you qualify.